# onQueryTextSubmit never called

Tags: android, android-activity, listener

In my activity I have a searchView that is correctly displayed but the listeners are never called when a user submits a query. What have I done wrong ?

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.list_container);

    SearchView searchView = (SearchView) findViewById(R.id.search_view);
    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String query) {
           listPresenter.onSearch(query);
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
            listPresenter.onSearch(query);
            return true;
        }
    });

}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the problem was coming from the `return true` that should be a `return false` inside `onQueryTextChange` and `onQueryTextSubmit`